# Orthonormal basis of $L^2( (0,a)\cup(b,c) )$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, orthonormal

I am studying Lebesgue spaces and appear the concept of orthonormal basis.  My professor told me that a classic result is the following: the set given by $$(\sqrt{2} \sin(n\pi x))_{n\geq 1}$$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(0,1)$. So he ask me how is possible obtain basis for $L^2$ on union of intervals in the form:  $\mathcal{E}:=(0,a)\cup(b,c)$.

**My question are: which is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathcal{E})$?, the same basis works for both $L^2(0,1)$ and $L^2(\mathcal{E})$ ?.**

Comment: if we consider $c=1$ and $0<a<b<1$, then the same basis that I mentioned for $L^2(0,1)$ works for $L^2((0,a)\cup(b,1))$, or not ?

Comment: Hint: in the case $0<a<b<1$, verify whether $L^2((0,a)\cup (b,1))= L^2(0,a) \oplus L^2(b,1)$

Comment: @Brozovic I do not know how proceed with the idea of direct sum. However, I was think in the following: if $L^2( (0,a)\cup (b,1) ) \subset L^2( (0,a)\cup [a,b] \cup(b,1) ) = L^2( 0,1 )$, then every element of that space can be expressed by linear combination of the basis $(\sqrt{2}\sin (n\pi x))_{n\geq 1}$. Is it correct ?

Comment: Further hint: First prove my previous hint and then note that if $H_1,H_2$ are two inner product spaces with Orthonormal bases say $\{e_m\}_{m \in I}$ and  $\{f_n\}_{n \in J}$ then  $\{(e_m,0),(0,f_n): m \in I, n \in J\}$ forms an Orthonormal bases for $H_1 \oplus H_2$

Comment: Note that the Orthonormal bases of $L^2(0,1)$  you have written, in order to make them elements of $L^2((0,a) \cup (b,1))$, you are basically looking at their restrictions on  $ (0,a) \cup (b,1)$. Are these restrictions still orthonormal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Orthonormal basis for $L^2(a,b)$**

Let $(a,b)$ be an interval . Then the inner product for $L^2(a,b)$ is given by, $$<f,g>=\frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^b f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$$ (Note that we have included the factor $\frac{1}{b-a}$ just to normalize our space to be a probability space.) Now we have the natural homeomorphism $\varphi:(a,b) \to (0,1)$ given by, $\varphi(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ .Now corresponding to your favourite Orthonormal basis of $L^2(0,1)$ say $\{e_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ consider $\{\tilde{e_n}\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ given by, $\tilde{e_n}(x):=e_n\circ\varphi(x)$ .

**Exercise 1:** Check that $\{\tilde{e_n}\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is an Orthonormal basis for $L^2(a,b)$

**Step 2: Look at the union of intervals**

If you are considering the union of $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)$ then either their union is a single interval namely $(\min(a_1,a_2),\max(b_1,b_2))$ or a union of two disjoint intervals. If the union is a single interval, then we already have an Orthonormal basis by Step 1. Otherwise, consider $\{\tilde{e_n}\}_{n \in \Bbb N},\{\tilde{f_m}\}_{m \in \Bbb N}$ for the two intervals obtained from Step 1 .

**Step 3: Looking at the direct sum**

As the set is disjoint union of two open intervals, it is easy to prove that,

**Exercise 2:** $L^2(\mathcal{E})=L^2(a_1,b_1) \oplus L^2(a_2,b_2)$ (in fact, as an orthogonal sum)

**Exercise 3:** $\{(\tilde{e_n},0),(0,\tilde{f_m}):m,n \in \Bbb N\}$ is an Orthonormal basis of $L^2(\mathcal{E})$ (where you extend $\tilde{e_n}$ to be $0$ on $(a_2,b_2)$ and $\tilde{f_n}$ to be $0$ on $(a_1,b_1)$ )

**Q.E.D**

Let me know if more details is required !

Comment: Thanks you are an excellent professor !!